# Norm operators bounded below implies almost uniform lower bound

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a hard time proving (or disproving) the following statement about continuous linear operators:

$$(\exists c>0:\forall j:\|T_j\|\geq c)\Rightarrow(\exists\delta>0:\forall n:\exists x\in X:\forall 1\leq j\leq n:|T_jx|\geq\delta)$$

where $T_j$ is a sequence of continuous linear functionals on a Banach space $X$, so $T_j:X\to\mathbb{R}$. Does anybody have any thoughts on this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: at the end of your statement, you wrote $T_jx\ge \delta$ ? Did you mean $\|T_jx\|$, or the operators are actually functionals $T_j: X\to\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @Svetoslav, sorry for being so unclear, I was indeed talking about functionals with domain $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Should it be $T_j x \geq \delta$ or $\lvert T_j x\rvert \geq \delta$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, You are indeed correct, thank you for finding my sloppy mistakes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an arbitrary $n$, if we have an $x_n\in X$ such that $T_j x_n \neq 0$ for $1 \leqslant j\leqslant n$, then we can scale by a large enough real number so that $\lvert T_j (tx_n)\rvert \geqslant \delta$ for $1\leqslant j \leqslant n$ whatever $\delta$ we prescribed.

So the problem reduces to the question whether we can always find such an $x_n$, or, in an equivalent formulation, whether

$$X \neq \bigcup_{j = 1}^n \ker T_j$$

for all $n$. The assertion $\lVert T_j\rVert \geqslant c$ for some $c > 0$ ensures that none of the $T_j$ is the zero functional, so $\ker T_j$ is a proper closed subspace of $X$ for all $j$. As a proper subspace, $\ker T_j$ has empty interior, so $\ker T_j$ is nowhere dense. Hence

$$N = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{\infty} \ker T_j$$

is a meagre subset of $X$, and by Baire's theorem $X \setminus N$ is dense, in particular $X\setminus N$ is nonempty.

Now take an $x_0 \in X\setminus N$, and for each $n$ choose $t_n \in \mathbb{R}$ so large that

$$\lvert T_j(t_n\cdot x_0)\rvert \geqslant \delta$$

for $1 \leqslant j \leqslant n$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know this comment is not allowed, but I really want to express my gratitude: thank you for this clever solution!